# How to store user name and id in specific table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to store the user name and user id in the data table. how can I store both of value in database?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        global $wpdb;
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $mteverest=$_POST['mteverest'];
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'pte_quiz';

        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'answer' => $mteverest,
                'user' => $current_user,
                'uid'=>
            )
        );
        echo "inserted";
        ?>
        <?php
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        global $wpdb;
        $current_username = wp_get_current_user()->data->user_nicename;
        $current_userid =  wp_get_current_user()->id;
        $mteverest=$_POST['mteverest'];
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'pte_quiz';
        $data_array = array(
                'answer' => $mteverest,
                'user' => $current_username,
                'uid'=> $current_userid
        );

         $insertResult = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_array, $format=NULL);

        echo "inserted";
        ?>
        <?php
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok sorry I edited this a few times. Tthis one should work. lLet me know!